# Matching group of words and printing then only using sed or awk

Tags: bash, awk, sed

With sed or awk, how could I match  and print only `organization` and `repo` from

`git@github.org.com/organization/repo.git` ?

My intention is to assign both values to variables to using in something that I'm building to create local folders for organizations and repositories.

The desired result would be `organization/repo` only.

Currently in order to proceed i'm using `cut -f2 -d':' | cut -f1 -d'` but I'm ashamed of push this .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you need to create 2 shell variables it may be better to prefer a BASH solution.

You can use `read` with `IFS='./':`:

```
IFS='./:' read -ra arr <<< 'git@github.org.com/organization/repo.git'
echo "${arr[3]}/${arr[4]}"
```

```
organization/repo
```

- `IFS='./:'` splits input string on DOT and `/`
  and :colon
- `read -a` populates an array from input text

Comment: How could I use this inside of a shellscript ? For example the git repo url is being retrieved by the command git config --get remote.origin.url

Comment: You can use: `IFS='./' read -ra arr < <(git config --get remote.origin.url )`

Comment: You dropped this $ ;) and yes... how silly of mine, i'm going to test it in a few minutes.

Comment: No `$` is not needed here since this is process substitution syntax

Comment: please just Update IFS='./:' so i can accept the answer. i need to split on : as well. ( already tested and working)